# How to save a figure in matplotlib by its variable name?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` saves the current figure. If I have multiple figures as variables in my workspace, e.g. `fig1`, `fig2`, and `fig3`, is it possible to save any of these figures based on their variable name, without first bringing them up as the current figure? E.g., I'd like to do something like:

`save('fig2', 'fig2_file.png')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Figure.savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig). It would look something like this:

```
fig1.savefig('fig1.png')
fig2.savefig('fig2.png')
fig3.savefig('fig3.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save individual figures by:

> `figX.savefig('figX_file.png')`

.